# Microchip TCPIP Stack over 18f4620

Tags: c, embedded, pic, tcp, microchip

Hello and thank you all for your time.

My question is the following: When using this microchip TCPIP stack, should it be mounted over any kind of scheduler/RTOS, or does this stack contain already the necessary handling for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Microchip stack has no requirement for an RTOS.  You just need to call the stack initialization in main, then have a while loop that processes the stack regularly something like.

```
main()
{
    StackInit();
    while(1)
    {
        StackTask();
    }
}
```

Of course you can use an RTOS if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The stack contains already all the necessary handling for it to work. You just need to create a cooperative-multitasking environment for it to run and that is as "malaugh" just said.

Of course if you want to actually use the stack, you can for example open a TCP socket as client or server and send/receive bytes through it.

But basically you just need to do that, open your socket and immediately start sending and receiving bytes. The stack takes care of everything else when you call it constantly in an infinite while loop.